# Arduino C - Can't make new methods and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, methods

So i am making a joy stick control a tri-Copter's motor power distribution. i get a few errors which do not make sense(i am a custome with `java` so if its a `C` thing please tell me what i got wrong).

Here is the code:

```
  int ledPin = 13;
  int potPinx = 0;
  int potPiny = 1;
  int motor1 = 2;
  int motor2 = 3;
  int motor3 = 4;

  void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  }

  void loop() 
  {
    int valx = analogRead(potPinx);
    int valy = analogRead(potPiny);
    //Serial.begin(9600);
    //Serial.println("PotX = " + potPinx +  " PotY = " + potPiny);

    int motorCurrents[] = processMovement(potPinx, potPiny, 100);
    int motorCurrent1 = motorCurrents[0];
    int motorCurrent2 = motorCurrents[1];
    int motorCurrent3 = motorCurrents[2];

    //Serial.println("Motor 1 = " + motorCurrent1 + " Motor 2 = " + motorCurrent2 + " Motor 2 = " + motorCurrent2);

    digitalWrite(motor1, motorCurrent1);
    digitalWrite(motor2, motorCurrent2);
    digitalWrite(motor3, motorCurrent3);

  }

  int[] processMovement(int x, int y, int total)  
  {
    int motor1x;
    int motor2x;
    int motor3x;
    int motor1y;
    int motor2y;
    int motor3y;
    int motor1;
    int motor2;
    int motor3;
    x = x - total/2;
    y = y - total/2;

    if(x > 0)
    {
      motor1x = x*2
      motor2x = x;
      motor3x = x*3;
    }
    else
    {
      x = x * (-1);
      motor1x = x*2;
      motor2x = x*3;
      motor3x = x;
    }


    if(y > 0)
    {
      motor1y = y*2
      motor2y = y;
      motor3y = y*3;
    }
    else
    {
      y = y * (-1);
      motor1y = y*2;
      motor2y = y*3;
      motor3y = y;
    }

    motor1 = (motor1x + motor1y)/2;
    motor2 = (motor2x + motor2y)/2;
    motor3 = (motor3x + motor3y)/2;

    return {motor1, motor2, motor3};


  }
}
```

so as you can see i made a method called `processMovement()` it returns an `array of ints`. i then make 3 individual `intagers` to represent each position in the `array` and output thier value to `Digital Pins` 2, 3, and 4. but for some reason the compiler says that i did not declare the `method` `processMovement()`  in the scope and that something is wrong with my declaration of an `int array`.

Here are the errors:

```
ArduinoJoyStick.ino:7:4: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
ArduinoJoyStick.ino: In function 'void loop()':
ArduinoJoyStick.ino:23:64: error: 'processMovement' was not declared in this scope
ArduinoJoyStick.ino: At global scope:
ArduinoJoyStick.ino:36:6: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
Error compiling.
```

Comment: Where is `ArduinoJoyStick.ino` and what is line 7 of it?   `int[] processMovement(int x, int y, int total)  ` is an error in C which seems to correspond to your error on line `36`, and the error on line `23` is clear; however line 7 by that reckoning would be `int motor1 = 2;` which is fine.

Comment: the weird `IDE` says at function `void loop()` and so its the 7th line of void loop. and `ArduinoJoyStick.ino` is the file(`ino` is the file type for arduino based C)

Comment: Arrays. You got arrays wrong. Everybody gets arrays wrong. C is such a special language. You cannot return an array from a function and you cannot assign stuff to an array and you cannot pass an array to a function though the language pretends you can, and you cannot have array values like `{1,2,3}`. If you want to use arrays in C you need to take your time and pretend to forget about all other languages and learn about arrays in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, arrays cannot be treated like values; they can't be returned from functions and they can't be assigned to using `{ }` syntax. Also, their size must be announced when they are declared.

A secondary problem is that you call the `processMovement` function before declaring it. Functions must be declared before they are called, the compiler won't "look ahead" in the file to see if there is a function of that name later on.

You need to design your functions to not return arrays. One way to do this is for the caller to declare the array and tell the called function where that array is, for example:

```
void processMovement(int x, int y, int total, int *output)  
{
    // same logic...

    output[0] = motor1;
    output[1] = motor2;
    output[2] = motor3;
}

void loop()
{
    // ...
    int motorCurrents[3];
    processMovement(potPinx, potPiny, 100, motorCurrents);    

    digitalWrite(motor1, motorCurrents[0]);  // no need for motorCurrent1 etc.

}
```

Comment: so i droped motorCurrents, and declared `motor1`, `motor2`, and `motor3` as `motorOutput1,motorOutput2,motorOutput3` globably. then made my return void and said `digitalWrite(motor1, motorOutput1);`. that solved it. (side comment: since i a trying to get `motorCurrents`, i dont know its value before calling the method so i can not have that as an input value.)